# sklearn Logistic Regression with n_jobs=-1 doesn't actually parallelize

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm trying to train a huge dataset with sklearn's logistic regression.
I've set the parameter n_jobs=-1 (also have tried n_jobs = 5, 10, ...), but when I open htop, I can see that it still uses only one core.

Does it mean that logistic regression just ignores the n_jobs parameter?

How can I fix this? I really need this process to become parallelized...

P.S. I am using sklearn 0.17.1

Answer (score 1):

the parallel process backend also depends on the solver method. if you want to utilize multi core, the `multiprocessing` backend is needed.

but solver like 'sag' can only use `threading` backend.

and also mostly, it can be blocked due to a lot of pre-processing.

Comment: it would be great if you could clarify with a working example using n_jobs on sklearn

Comment: How do you "enable the multiprocessing backend"?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons for it if you read their [instructions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) carefully.
Can you try this set of parameters:

```
    logit = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',
                       random_state=42,
                       C=0.2,
                       n_jobs=-1,
                       solver='sag',
                       multi_class='ovr',
                       max_iter=200,
                       verbose=10
                      )
```

And it takes one minute or two to start multiple threads.