# How to enable multicore processing with sklearn LogisticRegression?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Sklearn's LogisticRegression model refuses to run in parallel. I set n_jobs=-1, and also tried n_jobs=4. No luck -- only one core is engaged. I've run other sklearn models in parallel, e.g., RandomForestClassifier and XGBoostClassifier.

I'm running Python 2.7.12 with sklearn 0.18 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Other people have asked the same question (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620185/sklearn-logistic-regression-with-n-jobs-1-doesnt-actually-parallelize)), thus far without receiving any promising replies. I'm hoping my luck will be better.

Comment: what are you trying to run? AFAIK `LogisticRegression` doesn't support parallelism

Comment: There are many possible reasons. But luckily it's not that important. In all sane ml-tasks you would use cross-validation, and sklearns [LogisticRegressionCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html) is easily parallel.

Comment: @sascha that's a big call, often a single time-separated split is more appropriate than n-fold cross-validation, and in production applications you might just need to train the model as quickly as possible.

Comment: @maxymoo Concerns accepted! Of course you are right, that there are always use-cases. But most of them are not that common in regards to SO-questions.

Comment: As LogisticRegression don't support n_jobs, an alternative could be to use SGDClassifier which lets multicore processing, and could be more suitable if you have a big dataset but, you should find the best hyperparameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the doco for `LogisticRegresssion` it looks like the `n_jobs` parameter is only used for separate cross-validation folds (unlike the case for `RandomForestClassifier` where the individual trees are computed in parallel).

> n_jobs : int, default: 1
>
> Number of CPU cores used during the cross-validation loop. If given
>     a value of -1, all cores are used.

Comment: Thank you, Maxymoo. And Sascha too. I hadn't realized that the n_jobs parameter was limited to cross validation (and presumably grid search as well). I was doing some exploration, and wasn't interested in either of those things. I was hoping just to speed up the training process for a single model. Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

In the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/093e0cf14/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py#L792) of Logistic Regression you can see that there is a parameter "n_threads" which is explicitly set to 1. That parameter might be limiting the CPU usage.